# ¿Como hacer uso del cortar de palabras truncatewords en django?

Tags: python, django

tengo el siguiente codigo que me recorta las palabras pero, no puedo mostrar el contenido que ya fue recortado

## Codigo donde hago uso el truncateword

```
 <td class=" "><h5>{{ correspondencia.referencia| truncatewords:"4" }}</h5><a href="#" style:"color:blue;">leer mas ...</a></td>
```

¿como podria mostrar el contenido que esta oculto?